# Save data from gui in java

Tags: java, user-interface, save

I make method for student to show every student that I have om my GUI and i want to have options to save my GUi into the xml file.. My problem is that i have error null pointer exception

i solve problem problem for writig student that

i make private Composite `mSTUDENTChild`;

and i write every `studentChild = mSTUDENTChild;` and into save part i make this

```
 Control[] currentSTUDENTOnGui = mSTUDENTChild.getChildren();
```

My problem is to write subject that i have

```
public void displaySTUDENTTab(TabFolder tabFolderAdministration, CurrentData currentData){

        TabItem tbtmSTUDENT = new TabItem(tabFolderAdministration, SWT.NONE);
        tbtmSTUDENT.setText("STUDENT");

        ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite_7 = new ScrolledComposite(tabFolderAdministration, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        tbtmSTUDENT.setControl(scrolledComposite_7);
        scrolledComposite_7.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        scrolledComposite_7.setExpandVertical(true);

        List<STUDENT> allStudentNodes = currentData.getstudentNodes();


        final Composite studentChild = new Composite(scrolledComposite_7, SWT.NONE);
        studentChild.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        for(STUDENT studentNode: allStudentNodes){

            new studentNode(this, studentChild, SWT.NONE, studentNode);

            Composite subjectChild = new Composite(studentChild, SWT.NONE);
            GridLayout bladeGrid = new GridLayout(9, true);
            subjectChild.setLayout(bladeGrid);

            for(Blade bladeNode: studentNode.getBlades()){
                new BladeID(subjectChild, SWT.NONE, bladeNode);
            }
            msubjectChild = subjectChild;
        }
        mstudentChild = studentChild;

        scrolledComposite_7.setContent(studentChild);
        scrolledComposite_7.setMinSize(studentChild.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
        scrolledComposite_7.pack();
    }
```

And I make saveas method and it's now working this is my code for saving, I have class `SUBJECT`, `SUBJECTID` and `AddSubject`

```
 Control[] currentSTUDENTOnGui = studentChild.getChildren();
int noOfBCs = -1;
currentData.getStudentNodes().clear();
 for (int i = 0; i < currentSTUDENTOnGui.length; i++) {
    boolean isBCNode = false;
    SubjectNode subjectOnGuii = null;
    STUDENTNode nodeOnGuiSTUDENT = null;
    try {
        nodeOnGuiSTUDENT = (STUDENTNode) currentSTUDENTOnGui[i];
        isBCNode = true;
        noOfBCs++;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        subjectOnGuii = (SubjectNode) currentSTUDENTOnGui[i];
    }
    if (isBCNode) {
        STUDENT nodeWithDataSTUDENT = new STUDENT(nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText(), nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_1(), nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_2(), nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_3(),
        nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_4(), nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_5(), nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_6(), nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_7(), nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_8(), nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_9(), nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_10(),
        nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_11(), nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_12(), nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_13(), nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_14(), nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_15(), nodeOnGuiSTUDENT.getText_16());
        currentData.getStudentNodes().add(nodeWithDataSTUDENT);
        continue;
    }
    STUDENT lastNodeWithData = currentData.getStudentNodes().get(noOfBCs);
    SUBJECT subjectToAdd = new SUBJECT(subjectOnGuii.getId(), subjectOnGuii.getSessionType(), subjectOnGuii.getUser(), subjectOnGuii.getSupwd(), subjectOnGuii.getPort());
    lastNodeWithData.getSubject().add(subjectToAdd);
    currentData.getStudentNodes().set(noOfBCs, lastNodeWithData);
}
```

Comment: Since _"it's now working"_, what is your question?

Comment: `My problem is that i have error null pointer exception` - _where_ do you get that NPE? Did you try to debug your code to see why you get null there?

Comment: How to make this to work :).. My question is how to solve problem for "subjects" that I want to save because I have null pointer exception and in reality i don't have clue what is the problem

Comment: @Thomas i have problem in the line subjectOnGuii = (SubjectNode) currentSTUDENTOnGui[i]; i can't cast my subjects in the SubjectNode.. Yes I make debug and i enter in for loop and pass troguh loop first time and everything break after that

Comment: You shouldn't get a nullpointer exception on `subjectOnGuii = (SubjectNode) currentSTUDENTOnGui[i];` since casting null is always ok and `currentSTUDENTOnGui` should not be null at that point. So I suspect you have a different problem - please be as specific as you can if you want us to help you.

Comment: Btw, don't use exceptions for control flow, i.e. don't try to cast and then try something else in the catch block. Instead use `instanceof` to check whether the element is a `STUDENTNode` or not etc. (besides that the design might probably be improved but I consider that out of scope for this question).

Comment: Now in the line that i give you my app is breaking maybe the reason is that i show on GUI just Subject ID field not all data and I want to write hole data into xml About design i work for first time in java and I'm using SWT and of course that I want to improve design but to be honest I'm web developer and java is something new for me so if you have good tutorial or advice I'm open for everything ..